# React Components overlap each other

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

Component "SideBar", and other component such as "Subject" is overlapping and I don't know how to stop this.
I looked for other questions in StackOverFlow, and found that using flexbox is useful, but it didn't work for me as shown in the picture.
[image: Overlapped Components]
Here's my code.
App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

import SideBar from './sideBar/SideBar';
import Landing from './landing/Landing';
import Home from './home/Home'
import Subjects from './subjects/Subject'
import "./app.css";

const App = () => {
    return (
        <div>
            <BrowserRouter>
                <div className="app">
                    <Route path="/app" component={SideBar} />
                    <Route exact path="/" component={Landing} />
                    <Route exact path="/app" component={Home} />
                    <Route exact path="/app/subjects" component={Subjects} />
                </div>
            </BrowserRouter>
        </div>
    );
};

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

app.css:

```
.app {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: row;
}
```

Subject.js:

```
import React from "react";
import { Card, Button } from 'react-bootstrap';

const Subjects = () => {
    return (
        <Card style={{ width: '18rem' }}>
            <Card.Img variant="top" src="holder.js/100px180" />
            <Card.Body>
                    <Card.Title>Card Title</Card.Title>
                    <Card.Text>
                            Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of
                            the card's content.
                    </Card.Text>
                    <Button variant="primary">Go somewhere</Button>
            </Card.Body>
        </Card>
    )
};

export default Subjects;
```

SideBar.js:

```
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import { Link } from 'react-router-dom';
import { ProSidebar, Menu, MenuItem, SubMenu, SidebarContent, SidebarFooter, SidebarHeader } from 'react-pro-sidebar';
import 'react-pro-sidebar/dist/css/styles.css';
import { FiHome, FiLogOut, FiArrowLeftCircle, FiArrowRightCircle } from "react-icons/fi";
import { BiCog } from "react-icons/bi";
import { RiFilePaper2Fill } from "react-icons/ri";
import { AiFillTrophy } from "react-icons/ai";
import "./SideBar.css";

const Header = () => {
    const [menuCollapse, setMenuCollapse] = useState(false);

    const menuIconClick = () => {
        menuCollapse ? setMenuCollapse(false) : setMenuCollapse(true);
    };

    return (
        <>
            <div id="header">
                            {/* collapsed props to change menu size using menucollapse state */}
                    <ProSidebar collapsed={menuCollapse}>
                            <SidebarHeader>
                                <div className="logotext">
                                        {/* small and big change using menucollapse state */}
                                        <p>{menuCollapse ? "Logo" : "Big Logo"}</p>
                                </div>
                                <div className="closemenu" onClick={menuIconClick}>
                                            {/* changing menu collapse icon on click */}
                                    {menuCollapse ? (
                                            <FiArrowRightCircle/>
                                    ) : (
                                            <FiArrowLeftCircle/>
                                    )}
                                </div>
                            </SidebarHeader>
                            <SidebarContent>
                                <Menu iconShape="square">
                                    <MenuItem icon={<FiHome />}>
                                        Home
                                        <Link to="/app" />
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem icon={<RiFilePaper2Fill />}>
                                        Subjects
                                        <Link to="/app/subjects" />
                                    </MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem icon={<AiFillTrophy />}>Ranking</MenuItem>
                                    <MenuItem icon={<BiCog />}>Settings</MenuItem>
                                </Menu>
                            </SidebarContent>
                            <SidebarFooter>
                                <Menu iconShape="square">
                                        <MenuItem icon={<FiLogOut />}>
                                            Logout
                                            <Link to="/api/logout" />
                                        </MenuItem>
                                </Menu>
                            </SidebarFooter>
                    </ProSidebar>
            </div>
        </>
    );
};

function mapStateToProps({ auth }) {
    return { auth };// === { auth: state.auth }
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps)(Header);
```

SideBar.css:

```
#header {
        position: absolute;
        width: 220px;
        display: flex;
}
#header .pro-sidebar {
        height: 100vh;
}
#header .closemenu {
        color: #000;
        position: absolute;
        right: 0;
        z-index: 9999;
        line-height: 20px;
        border-radius: 50%;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 22px;
        top: 55px;
        cursor: pointer;
}
#header .pro-sidebar {
        width: 100%;
        min-width: 100%;
}
#header .pro-sidebar.collapsed {
    width: 80px;
    min-width: 80px;
}
#header .pro-sidebar.collapsed ul .pro-inner-item {
    font-size: 0px;
}

#header .pro-sidebar-inner {
    background-color: white;
    box-shadow: 0.5px 0.866px 2px 0px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
    /*
        周りの枠線
    */
}
#header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout {
        overflow-y: hidden;
}
#header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout .logotext p {
    /*
        Logo and Big Logo above
    */
        font-size: 20px;
        padding: 0 20px;
        color: rgb(202, 15, 15);
        font-weight: bold;
}
#header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul {
        padding: 0 0px;
}
#header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item {
    /*
        color of the list(Home, Subjects, etc...)
    */
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        margin: 10px 0px;
        font-weight: bold;
}
#header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item .pro-icon-wrapper {
    /*
        Each Icon's properties
    */
        background-color: #fbf4cd;
        color: rgb(0, 0, 0);
        border-radius: 3px;
}
#header .pro-sidebar-inner .pro-sidebar-layout ul .pro-inner-item .pro-icon-wrapper .pro-item-content {
        color: #000;
}

#header .logo {
    padding: 20px;
}

@media only screen and (max-width: 720px) {
    html {
        overflow: hidden;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Firstly you need to share the styling of the sidebar

The sidebar is not acting like the flex item of the parent flex container, It is taking some other styling.

The `<Subjects />` component is acting as the first item of your flex container

If you do not intend to change the styling of the `<Sidebar />` component then what you can do is give a `margin-left` either to the Flex container or the first flex item

Comment: Sorry I didn't add SideBar.js, as it was quite long, and mess around.
I added now.

Comment: You have given position: absolute to the Sidebar. This takes the element out of the flow and it will be positioned absolutely with respect to the nearest parent who has position: relative, If you do not have any parent with position: relative which is your case, Then the element with position: absolute is positioned relative to the browser window which is your case. So you need to change this styling.